# for loop does not finish iterating in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I am new to Python and programming in general as well. 
Let me first explain what I try to accomplish with the code below, then I will explain the problem I encounter.

The purpose of the program is to extract the urls of 10-k files from the EDGAR database. 10-k files are essentially annual reports for the publicly listed companies.

tk_sr_3q is a python file that I created previously that contains a list with about 100 thousand elements. All elements are urls of search results of 10-k file in the EDGAR database.

For examples:

http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=51143&type=10-k&dateb=&owner=exclude&count=100

http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=1595703&type=10-k&dateb=&owner=include&count=100

Some companies have a lot of 10-k files, some have a few and some don't have any. I want to get no more than six 10-k file urls from each company, then write them in a list format in a text file.

When I run the program, it does not finish. But it produced the text file that contains about three thousand elements which is not possible if it ran correctly.

Thank you very much for reading my question.

```
import tk_sr_3q
tkfd_url_list_file = open('tkfd_url_list.txt', 'w')

for url in tk_sr_3q.list:
    tk_sr_src = requests.get(url)
    tk_sr_src_soup = BeautifulSoup(tk_sr_src.content)
    fd_link_list = tk_sr_src_soup.find_all('a', {'id': 'documentsbutton'}, limit=6)
    for link in fd_link_list:
        tkfd_url = 'http://www.sec.gov'+link['href']
        tkfd_url_list_file.write("%s" % "'"+tkfd_url+"'"+',')

tkfd_url_list_file.close()
```

Comment: umm, since you are never changing the "url var" in your first "for" it will never get out of the loop,
maybe you typed "url" instead of tkfd_url?

Comment: If a for loop never breaks, it's either because it's too slow, or because the structure iterates cyclically, like for example a circular linked list

Comment: what exactly `tk_sr_3q.list` is ?

Comment: I'm confused, are you saying that the resulting file has a single list with 3,000 elements, or that you have 3,000 URLs total across many different companies?

Comment: Hi. haifzhan. tk_sr_3q.list is the list that contains 100 thousand urls like the ones I have shown in the post.

Comment: You probably want to add a newline to the end of the data you pass to `tkfd_url_list_file.write()` otherwise everything is going to appear on one line. For debugging purposes, you might want to try printing the same data to the screen.

Comment: What makes you think the program won't finish? Sounds like it's just slow, as is to be expected when attempting to download 100,000 web pages.

Comment: Hi. Ryan. The resulting file has 3000 elements which is not correct with the input of 100,000 because most companies have 10-k files. The correct result should have about 300,000 elements.

Comment: Thanks. martineau. That is a good idea, I will give it a try now.

Comment: Also consider tkfd_url_list_file.flush() after you write a line